# Unordered list items not read by Narrator

Tags: html, accessibility

Unordered list items not read by Narrator

I have an unordered list as below, but the list items are not read when `<li>` elements are focused. Any suggestions?

Whenever the `<li>` elements are focused, I want the aria-label to be read by Narrator.

```
<div id="container">
            <ul>
              <li id="Action1" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" role="listitem" aria-label="Action1">
              </li>
              <li id="Action2" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" role="listitem" aria-label="Action2">
              </li>
              <li id="Action3" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" role="listitem" aria-label="Action3">
              </li>
              <li id="Action4" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" role="listitem" aria-label="Action4">
              </li>
              <li id="Action5" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" role="listitem" aria-label="Action5">
              </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend removing the `tabindex`, `aria-disabled`, and `role` attributes.

The `tabindex` attribute is most likely the source of your problems.

> A negative value (usually tabindex="-1") means that the element is not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation, but could be focused with Javascript or visually.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

By setting the `tabindex` to `-1`, you're telling the browser that the item should be removed from the tab order and only accessed programmatically. I suspect this may be why Narrator is not finding it. There should be no need to use `tabindex` unless you need non-clickable content to be focusable for some reason.

The `aria-disabled` attribute, when set to `false`, is the same as not having it. This is unnecessary and should be removed.

https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-disabled

A role of `listitem` on a `<li>` element is also redundant and unnecessary. The `<li>` element already has an implicit role of `listitem`. This role is intended more for generic `<div>` elements that are used to create a list-like structure.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Listitem_role#Best_practices

Comment: thorough answer (+1) but the tabindex is indeed the issue here. `tabindex="-1"` essentially removes it from the accessibility tree built by the screen reader. If it still doesn't function add `tabindex="0"` to the `<ul>` as that makes it focusable (although odds are if you need to do this you are using the screen reader wrong or have a problem elsewhere that is breaking the accessibility tree).